# Location permission does not always show up

Tags: android, location, android-permissions

I am facing two issues:

- The app shows the popup to request location only sometimes, even tho the permission has not been granted yet or was denied (but not "deny and do not ask again")
- On Android 10 (API 29) it seems that "Allow all the time" box does not appear, but only "Allow while using the app, Deny, Deny and don't ask again" even if this Android Version should allow it.

My application should need `FINE_LOCATION` and `BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permissions

This is my code:

**manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

**MainActivity**

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},
                Utils.PERMISSION_SMS_RECEIVE);
    }

    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                Utils.PERMISSION_SMS_SEND);
    }

    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                Utils.PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }

    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                Utils.PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                    Utils.PERMISSION_ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
        }
    }
```

The SMS permission always shows up when it's not granted, but location permission shows up only sometimes and I find its behaviour weird.

Comment: background location can only be asked if user has granted fine_location. So, update your code accordingly.

Comment: @primo fine_location is already there

Comment: is it granted by the user?

Comment: if normal location permission is granted by the user then only you can ask background lcoation permission. Otherwise it wont ask for that

Comment: Well, no dialog prompt get shown, not even the one for normal permission :/

Comment: actually it might be asking the permissions but I all dialog might be getting overriden.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the permissions like. You are asking all the permissions separately. So might be all the permissions dialogs are appearing but are on top of the other.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS,
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ),
                REQUEST_CODE
            );
        }
```

For asking background location first ensure that your app is having normal location permission granted.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION),
                        Utils.PERMISSION_ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                    );
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: wowzie thank you it works! I placed those ifs one under the other, so why aren't the permissions overriding one another here? Well it works anyways, just a curiosity

Comment: ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission accepts array of permissions.So, we do not need to explicitly add multiple ifs to manage this

Comment: sorry for being annoying, but I meant the if requesting SMS and Location and then the if requesting BACKGROUND_LOCATION. I placed them under one another

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you are trying to say. Edit the question with the code you have implemented.